# Logistic regression for disease detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to do a logistic regression model, I have 140 test results from 140 people, each test has 300 points (x,y) representing mass and intensity and I have 140 labels of whether or not they have the disease (0,1)

The 300 points for each exam look like this:

```
499.871 551
499.883 552
499.896 566
499.909 514
499.921 503
499.934 462
499.946 507
499.959 467
499.972 408
499.984 419
499.997 457
500.010 469
.
.
.
```

If x,y graph looks like this:

[image: graph]

The problem is that the examples I find of Logistic Regression have one data per variable (x, y), for example this diabetes dataset [DATASET](https://github.com/gonzalezgouveia/clases-youtube/blob/main/diabetes-logistic/diabetes.csv)

In that dataset a person has a glucose value, BMI (x, y). In my problem I have 300 (x,y) values.

I am generating an example for my problem with random data, but I don't know if handling a three-dimensional array will solve that problem.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Training data
exams = np.random.rand(140, 300, 2)  # Example of generating random data
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=140)  # Example of generating random labels

# Flatten the exam data
flattened_exams = exams.reshape(140, -1)

# Create and fit the logistic regression model
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(flattened_exams, labels)

# Test data (example)
test_exams = np.random.rand(10, 300, 2)  # Example of generating random test data
flattened_test_exams = test_exams.reshape(10, -1)

# Make predictions on the test data
predictions = model.predict(flattened_test_exams)

# Print the predictions
print("Predictions:", predictions)
```

Would it be ok to manage my training data like this? Or what other algorithm could I use to address my problem?

Comment: Your actual question (it is not that clear...) seems to be how to handle a **multiple-output** logistic regression; however, this is not a *programming* question (you show some sample code, but you do not report any issues or errors with it), but a question about ML theory and/or methodology, hence it seems off-topic here. Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: In any case, many scikit-learn models can handle multi-output data. It also includes a [`MultiOutputClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier) as a wrapper for those who cannot (including the standard logistic regression). See the section [1.12.3. Multiclass-multioutput classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-multioutput-classification) in the docs.

Comment: have you tried isolation forest to locate anomalies in the data?  by analyzing where clustering is occurring you may get a better understanding of the trends in the data.